# How to send Cyrillic data with indy10 Delphi

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, indy

When I send some Cyrillic text in the web site that text is displayed with "?????????"....
Here is my sending function:

```
http := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
http.HandleRedirects := true;
http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
http.Request.ContentType:='multipart/form-data';
param:=TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
param.AddFormField('adtitle','Текст на кирилица');
param.AddFormField('area','Текст явергсдфсдфадфас');
http.Post('http://www.example.com/',param);
```

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: i don't know... i have Delphi 2009 - indy10 is built-in  
but when i open source folder i found 2 indy folders one indy9 and other indy10

Comment: Indy 9 does not support Delphi 2009.  It was an error on Embarcadero's part to include Indy 9 in 2009's installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
param.AddFormField('adtitle', 'Текст на кирилица', 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
param.AddFormField('area', 'Текст явергсдфсдфадфас', 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

Comment: @user789546, it seems that you are using some older version of Indy. Then try removing the `utf-8` parameter: `param.AddFormField('adtitle', 'Текст на кирилица').ContentTransfer := '8bit';`

Comment: @TreantBG: Like Darin said, you are using an old version. You need to upgrade to the latest Indy 10 release. Download and installation instructions are on Indy's website: http://www.indyproject.org.

Comment: OK it worked!!
but the symbols are encoded again like this: =D0=A1=D0=BE=D1=84=D0=B8=D1=8F
how to fixed it?

Comment: They would only be encoded that way if the `ContentTransfer` property is set to 'quoted-printable'.