# Delphi Indy Send POST data in Cyrillic

Tags: delphi, post, send, indy

I want to send Cyrillic post data with delphi using indy 10.
Ok i know how to send data but when i send something written or Cyrillic the post data response is with some encoded signs.
there is my code

```
  http := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
  http.HandleRedirects := true;
  http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
  http.Request.ContentType:='multipart/form-data';
  param:=TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  param.AddFormField('com','offers');
  param.AddFormField('op','new');
  param.AddFormField('MAX_FILE_SIZE','1048576');
  param.AddFormField('offer[secid]','34');
  param.AddFormField('offer[fullname]',UserArray[0], 'utf-8');
  param.AddFormField('offer[email]',UserArray[1]);
  param.AddFormField('offer[phone]',UserArray[2]);
  param.AddFormField('offer[url]',UserArray[4]);
  param.AddFormField('offer[city]','София', 'utf-8');
  param.AddFormField('offer[offer_buysell]','sell');
  param.AddFormField('offer[catid]','95');
  param.AddFormField('offer[title]',AdArray[0], 'utf-8');

  param.AddFile( 'image[0]', AdArray[3], 'image/jpeg' );

  param.AddFormField('offer[description]',AdArray[1], 'utf-8');
  param.AddFormField('offer[price]',AdArray[2]);
  param.AddFormField('offer[offer_end]','180');
  param.AddFormField('offer[email_onquestion]','1');
  param.AddFormField('iagree','1');
  param.AddFormField('btnSaveOffer','Изпрати', 'utf-8');
  valid:=true;
  url:='http://127.0.0.1/POST.php';
  text:=http.Post(url,param);
```

this is the response from my POST.php

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

[image: there is the site response]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322442/how-to-send-cyrillic-data-with-indy10-delphi

Comment: then the problem was other the Cyrillic symbols ware "?????" now they are something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling `AddFormField()` to encode text values using UTF-8, and then the UTF-8 octets are being additionally encoded during transmission using MIME's `quoted-printable` encoding,  which is the default setting for the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property for text data. You are seeing the quoted-printable text in your PHP output.  If you want PHP to receive raw UTF-8 octets instead, set the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to '8bit' or 'binary' instead, eg:

```
param.AddFormField('offer[fullname]',UserArray[0], 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

Otherwise, your PHP code will have to decode the quoted-printable data using the [quoted-printable-decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) function.

Comment: well i know that your solution works, but i have certain problems with my delphi and my indy10.... it sends me error at .ContentTransfer
  So i have personal request to you. Can you compile my small project and give me link to download the exe file?

this is the link to my project - http://www.mediafire.com/?zlblrkciri8fvzk

Comment: The `ContentTransfer` property was not available in the version of Indy (10.5.7) that shipped with Delphi XE.  It is a fairly recent addition in 10.5.8, which is available in Indy's SVN.

Comment: I wast try to upgrade my Embarcadero RAD Studio XE 3 TIMES...and i cant do it.. Please can you do that i ask from you? Can you compile my project and send me link to download it?

Comment: @TreantBG: Instructions are on Indy's website. What exactly are you having trouble with? Giving you a precompiled executable (and no, I will not do that for you) would be pretty useless if you cannot recompile the program yourself afterwards when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your "encoded signs" are Cyrillic in UTF8 encoding. You can decode them manually using the [correspondent encoding table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024). For example

D0 A1 D0 BE D1 84 D0 B8 D1 8F -> София

Comment: good but i don't want to decode them, but to send them in the correct way. i don't have access to the website that i want to send the POST data.

Comment: If PHP is not decoding them automatically, then your PHP script needs to decode them manually, or else you have to tell Indy to disable its encoding, as I showed you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP server receives the UTF-8 encoded strings in quoted printable format. To verify this, check if the application hits this line in IdMulitpartFormData:

```
FContentTransfer := sContentTransferQuotedPrintable;
```

However the PHP side should be able to handle this transfer mode.

Comment: yes in the file this line is correct. But my Embarcadero RAD Studio XE have some problem. When i want to see the file (Ctrl + click) an error shows up "Unable to locate file IdMulitpartFormData.pas" and the application still works...