# How to send big data from delphi to a remote php script and wait for answer?

Tags: php, delphi, http-post

*I am in risk of being very criticized over this question, because it might have been answered here, but I do not know to look right for it. I tried to get an answer in Foruns, but people bother to show up and say "I don't know".*

I usually use `TIdHTTP` to call a remote `PHP` script and receive some data, but only when I need to communicate with `REST` server inputting the data directly as a parameter.

Now I need to send some big `JSON object` (*encoded and much more than 255 bytes*) and I do not know how to do it in `Delphi`. I know that it should be through `POST` method, but how to send it from `Delphi`? And how to receive it in `PHP`, `$request[]`?

I also need a way to do it and then wait for an answer from the server, in form of other `JSON object`, encoded of course. It should be very simple. I have a DB online and I want to trade some data encrypted.

*Thank you for your help!*

Comment: I just answered this a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897521/post-json-data-to-restful-datasnap-server-from-delphi-client/17917259#17917259

Comment: But the content is not captured by `DataSnap` in my case, it is for P `PHP`.

Comment: @JanDoggen, I used your client code, but how to receive it in PHP, $post?

Comment: Found a not very beautiful way in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750222/delphi-indy-send-post-data-in-cyrillic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi doesn't have a library for that purpose so you will have to use one of the REST client libraries that can be found on the web.

[This](https://github.com/jamiei/SimpleRestClient/) one should suit your needs just nicely.

[Here](http://jamiei.com/blog/2013/01/simple-rest-client-for-delphi/) is an easy example showing how to use it.

Comment: These `putParams.Add('title=Buy milk');` are going to be inserted in the final URL to be sent?